# Linux + how to verify mirror configuration on linux red-hat with cfggen utility

Tags: raid

I have an IBM blade server with RedHat Linux installed.

How can we check to see if we have both disks running as a mirror, or if everything is only running on a single disk? What commands can I use to discover this?

I'm trying to use the cfggen utility to verify this configuration.

`./cfggen controller DISPLAY`

Please advise on how to find the controller number.

from cfggen docs:

```
   NAME
   cfggen  -  Configures the Integrated Raid (IR) functionality of the HP
   SAS controllers used in LSI-1068-based HP SAS controllers.

   SYNOPSIS
   cfggen controller# command parameters

          controller#
                    A unique controller number is assigned by the utility
                    to each PCI function found in the system.   Only  PCI
                    functions  on  controller  chips  recognized  by this
                    utility are assigned numbers.




  ./cfggen 
     LSI Logic IR Configuration Utility 2.00.30
     cfggen <controller #> <command> <parameters> ...
     where <controller #> is:
     Number between 0 and 255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only have one of them in your machine:

> ./cfggen 0 [command] [parameters]

Normally numbering should start from 0 as described in your question ...

Comment: I get the:  ./cfggen 0 DISPLAY
LSI Logic IR Configuration Utility 2.00.30
cfggen: couldn't open /dev/mptctl!
cfggen: make sure the mptctl driver is loaded!

Comment: Have you ensured the mptctl driver is loaded? What does lsmod tell you?

Comment: lsmod | grep -i raid
dm_raid45              66509  0 
dm_message              6977  1 dm_raid45
dm_region_hash         15681  1 dm_raid45
dm_log                 14529  3 dm_mirror,dm_raid45,dm_region_hash
dm_mod                 62201  5 dm_mirror,dm_multipath,dm_raid45,dm_log
dm_mem_cache            9537  1 dm_raid45

Comment: from lsmod what I need to think?